# How to decide between RPC and REST for APIs?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, rpc

I have made an application where the user will send the Program in either C or Python and Input via STDIN, and my API will return back the output of Program in JSON Format.

Nodejs/Expressjs Code :

```
route.post('/exec', (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.body.lang === 'c')
        cExec(req, res)
    if(req.body.lang === 'py3')
        py3Exec(req, res)
})
```

And after the code execution in `py3Exec() and cExec()`, I wrote this to send back the output, using Exit Codes:

```
if(code === 0)
            {
                if(stdout === req.body.output)
                    res.send({
                        "result": "AC",
                        "output": stdout
                    })
                    else
                    res.send({
                        "result": "WA",
                        "output": stdout
                    })
            }
            else
            {
                res.send({
                    "result": "ERR",
                    "error": stderr
                })
}
```

https://github.com/vkartik97/Online-IDE-API/blob/master/routes/run.js#L41
So, this API is REST. I wanted to know if this is Perfect way for this Use Case or if RPC should have been used as REST is used only for Resources from Server whereas RPC is used for Function Invocation(which is my case, maybe).

Thanks!

Comment: Not directly related, but I hope you realize that your scheme allows anyone to run any arbitrary code on your machine, e.g. read and/or delete everything.

Comment: Thanks. I have planned to use Docker for this case.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's not really a big deal which way you go, a lot will depend on the rest of the application. If all your application does is consume code, run it, and provides an output then either would most likely be fine.

You obviously can see how this might be an RPC call, with something like `/exec`, but it could also easily be a REST call, especially if you wanted to add some form of logging. For example: `POST /program` could be designed to consume some code, create a "program" in a database, run the code, and log the output along side the program in the database. You'd then return the program and it's response to the client.

If you're literally just consume code, running it, and giving an output back across HTTP then I'd be tempted to go with a JSON-RPC sort of endpoint for simplicity and to reveal intent (simply triggering an action).

Much depends on the future of your application and how much bigger it might become, and what other functionality you will have. If you're going to have a 90% RESTful API and a couple endpoints as a JSON-RPC, then I'd just go with a REST API for everything for consistency.

Comment: `but it could also easily be a REST call, especially if you wanted to add some form of logging.`
Will logging make REST Call Stateful?

Comment: Think of it more like creating a program and response, rather than logging the output of a program. In that case it's basically making a CRUD application, where you could query the same program later on and see the date it was run, the output, etc. (if you decided to expand to this level).